# Application icon corrupt in Android Market

Tags: android, icons, apk

I've recently published an app in the Android Market. My APK contains icons for res/drawable-hdpi, drawable-ldpi and drawable-mdpi. The icon files are perfectly valid - saved by Adobe Illustrator and show without problems in all browsers, Photoshop, Paint and Paint.NET. Icons are grayscale, but stored in 32Bit PNG.

For some reason, Android Market on phones and Developer Console show a garbled version of the same icon. It looks like my nice gradients are reduced to dotted, black and white mess.

Now, I suspected pngcrush / some similar APK optimisations, but the optimised, 8-bit PNG in the final APK are still perfectly renderable in all browsers etc.  Also, the menu on the phone renders it without problems.

Any help appreciated.

ANSWERED:The cause appears to be in the scaling algorithm used by Android Market backend. I've resolved the issue by replacing pure black surfaces RGB(0,0,0) with almost-entirely-black RGB(1,1,1) and the problem's gone away.

Comment: My first guess would probably be pngcrush too, but it might be a little easier for people to comment if you post up an example of your original file to inspect as well as a screenshot of the garbled output.

Answer (score 1):

The cause appears to be in the scaling algorithm used by Android Market backend. I've resolved the issue by replacing pure black surfaces RGB(0,0,0) with almost-entirely-black RGB(1,1,1) and the problem's gone away.